# create login for different user role

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

How to create login for different user i.e in my case there is two user (client and advertizer) and I want to redirect to specify page according to user type, here is my models.py and views.py, and also how to check authentication for different user type, and there is only one login page for all users:

```
# models.py        
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# Create your models here.
class Client(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, related_name='client_profile')
    #first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    #last_name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    #username = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    buisness_name= models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    USER_TYPE_CHOICES = (
        ('c', 'client'),
        ('a', 'advertizer'),
    )
    type_user = models.CharField(max_length=20, default='c', choices=USER_TYPE_CHOICES)

class Advertizer(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, related_name='advertizer_Profile')
    USER_TYPE_CHOICES = (
        ('c', 'client'),
        ('a', 'advertizer'),
    )
    type_user = models.CharField(max_length=20, default='a', choices=USER_TYPE_CHOICES)

# views.py
def user_login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # First get the username and password supplied
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        password = request.POST.get('password')

        # Django's built-in authentication function:
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)

        # If we have a user
        if user:
            #Check it the account is active
            if user.is_active:
                # Log the user in.
                login(request)
                if request.Client.user.type_user == 'c':
                    # Send the user back to some page.
                    # In this case their homepage.
                    return render(request, 'client.html')
                else:
                    # If account is not active:
                    return HttpResponse("Your account is not active.")
            else:
                print("Someone tried to login and failed.")
                print("They used username: {} and password: {}".format(username, password))
                return HttpResponse("Invalid login details supplied.")
        else:
            #Nothing has been provided for username or password.
            return render(request, 'login.html', {})
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to models - `Client` and `Advertizer`. When you got client from user that have only `Advertizer`, it will raise attribute error. (Cause your user object just have one of client or advertizer object)

You have few choices.

First, just move `type_user` to your `User` model. Then you just get your user type from user. like below

```
if request.user.type_user == 'c':
    ...
```

I recommend this method cause user_type is quite important information and you may divide it very often. So just add it to user and make your own `UserManager`. Then you can just call like `User.objects.client.all()`.

Second, easy way for now is just add `try`/`except`. You got error from the user don't related to `Client` object. So just add try and if raise attribute error, it's for `Advertizer` type user. Like below

```
try:
    type_user = request.user.client.type_user
except AttributeError:
    type_user = request.user.advertizer.type_user

if type_user == 'c':
    # Send the user back to some page.
```

It's easy way, but you have to add try/except for every time you want to divide your user model. So it's easy to add it to your user model itself.